# Logstash ignores(?) one grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

This is my config:

```
input{

        beats {
                port => 55556

        }


}

filter {
  if "iis" in [tags] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{WORD:S-SiteName} %{WORD:S-ComputerName} %{IPORHOST:S-IP} %{WORD:CS-Method} %{URIPATH:CS-URI-Stem} %{NOTSPACE:CS-URI-QUERY} %{NUMBER:S-Port}$ %{NUMBER:SC-Win32-Status} %{NUMBER:SC-Bytes} %{NUMBER:CS-Bytes} %{NUMBER:Time-Taken}"}
    }
  }
}

filter {
  if "nx" in [tags] {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\] (?<LogLevel>\[\w+\s*\]) (?<thread>\[\s*\d*\]) (?<snName>\[\w*\]) (?<snId>\[\d*\s*\d*\]) %{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
    }
  }
}



output{
        if "nx" in [tags] {

                elasticsearch {
                        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                        index => "nx-%{+YYYY.ww}"
                        user => "user"
                        password => "pass"
                }
        }

        if "iis" in [tags] {

                elasticsearch {
                        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                        index => "iis-%{+YYYY.ww}"
                        user => "user"
                        password => "pass"
                }
        }

}
```

Here's a log sample:

```
[2018-02-18 15:19:04.668] [INFO ] [   155] [AliveReportCommand] [875076019 53033] - ProcessRequest Ended: elapsed time=00:00:00.0967851, _parser.Device.IsSuccess=False
[2018-02-18 15:25:32.716] [DEBUG] [   181] [] [] - Web Facade called: streamIDParam=-1
```

This log corresponds to the "nx" logs.
For some reason it just does not get ingested. I ran grok simulation using the grok above and that code and it worked out great. However, it's like the "nx" filter is completely ignored. Even if I eliminate the "IIS" filter, still no info would show up on Kibana. Also no errors whatsoever in Logstash. I have the same setup for both using Filebeat:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths: c:\logs\*\*.log
  exclude_files: ['mybeat.*']
  tags: ["nx"]
  multiline.pattern: '^\['
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\*\*.log
  tags: ["iis"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so embarrassed...

The problem wasnt with the filter to begin with.
It was with the timestamp set on Kibana.
After selecting the right field it showed up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use only one filter.In your code you used two filter keywords.

```
 filter {
      if "iis" in [tags] {
        grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{WORD:S-SiteName} %{WORD:S-ComputerName} %{IPORHOST:S-IP} %{WORD:CS-Method} %{URIPATH:CS-URI-Stem} %{NOTSPACE:CS-URI-QUERY} %{NUMBER:S-Port}$ %{NUMBER:SC-Win32-Status} %{NUMBER:SC-Bytes} %{NUMBER:CS-Bytes} %{NUMBER:Time-Taken}"}
        }
      }
    if "nx" in [tags] {
        grok {
          match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\] (?<LogLevel>\[\w+\s*\]) (?<thread>\[\s*\d*\]) (?<snName>\[\w*\]) (?<snId>\[\d*\s*\d*\]) %{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Afraid that changes nothing.